# How to Fire onSearch event with react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have an `<InputSearch/>` component as a wrapper around `<input type="search">` that receives `onSearch` props as a callback when user press `enter`. How do i test that the callback will be called with react-testing-library?

Component i want to test:

```
const Search = ({ className, onSearch, placeholder }) => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('')

  const handleChange = e => {
    setSearchValue(e.target.value)
  }

  const search = (value, e) => {
    onSearch(value)
  }

  return (
    <SearchInput
      data-testid="search-input"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onSearch={search}
    />
  )
}
```

I have tried:

```
describe('Search', () => {
  const fakeOnSearch = jest.fn()
  const fakeProps = {
    className: 'fake-class-name',
    onSearch: fakeOnSearch,
    placeholder: 'fakesearch'
  }

  const { getByTestId, getByText, getByPlaceholderText } = render(<Search {...fakeProps} />)
  const node = getByTestId('search-input')

  afterEach(cleanup)

  it('calls onSearch callback', () => {
    fireEvent.keyPress(node, { key: "Enter", code: 13, charCode: 13 })
    expect(fakeOnSearch).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  })

})
```

test result:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledTimes(1)

Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `SearchInput`?

Comment: You have to mock `SearchInput` and call `onSearch` of fake SearchInput then check `jest.fn`

Comment: The answer depends on the implementation of `SearchInput`. It will be helpful if you share its code

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors I did not realize the fact that react is not implementing onsearch event on input. My bad.